# Python Django Pyrebase5

Tags: python, django, pip, pycharm, pyrebase

I tried every solution but I can't be able to remove this error, I think pyrebase5 is installed in my pycharm but  I always got this error. I am using pip 20.3.3 and Python 3.7.7. and pyrebase5. please help me, I am stuck in it.

File "E:\Hafr_Project\Hafr_Project\Hafr\HafrApp\urls.py", line 3, in 
from . import views
File "E:\Hafr_Project\Hafr_Project\Hafr\HafrApp\views.py", line 3, in 
from pyrebase import pyrebase
File "C:\Users\mians\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyrebase_*init*_.py", line 1, in 
from .pyrebase import initialize_app
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrebase.pyrebase'

Comment: did you install pyrebase

Comment: yes of course, when we use pip install pyrebase its gives errors, but pip install pyrebase5 working fine

Comment: `pip install pyrebase4` works fine for me.